RPC Request TIMEOUT: Method is not present in the message
I have followed a documentation on controlling gpio port. https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/esp8266/gpio/
The problem I have been facing is RPC Request TIMEOUT.
This is the main issue
java.lang.RuntimeException: Method is not present in the message!



is there anyone who is familiar with this issue?
For my setup i am using gpio 5 to control the D1 relay to turn on and off. the relay is connected to my esp8266 and I am using arduino 1.18.19 for programming
Arduino logs

    #include <ArduinoJson.h>
    #include <PubSubClient.h>
    #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

    #define WIFI_AP ""
    #define WIFI_PASSWORD ""
    #define TOKEN ""
    #define GPIO_PIN 5  // Using GPIO5 for this example

    char thingsboardServer[] = "";

    WiFiClient wifiClient;
    PubSubClient client(wifiClient);

    int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
    boolean gpioState = false;  // We assume that the GPIO is initially LOW

    void setup() {
        Serial.begin(115200);
        pinMode(GPIO_PIN, OUTPUT);  // Set GPIO5 as an output pin
        digitalWrite(GPIO_PIN, HIGH); // Ensure the pin starts in the LOW state
        InitWiFi();  // Initialize WiFi connection
        client.setServer(thingsboardServer, 1883);  // Set MQTT server
        client.setCallback(on_message);  // Set callback function for incoming messages
    }

    void loop() {
        if (!client.connected()) {
            reconnect();  // Reconnect if the client is disconnected
        }
        client.loop();  // Process incoming messages
    }

    // Callback function for when a message is received
    void on_message(const char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
        Serial.println("Message received");

        char json[length + 1];
        strncpy(json, (char*)payload, length);
        json[length] = '\0';

        Serial.print("Topic: ");
        Serial.println(topic);
        Serial.print("Message: ");
        Serial.println(json);

        DynamicJsonDocument doc(200);
        DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, json);

        if (error) {
            Serial.print("deserializeJson() failed: ");
            Serial.println(error.c_str());
            return;
        }

        const char* method = doc["method"];

        if (strcmp(method, "getGpioStatus") == 0) {
            // Handle getGpioStatus method
            String responseTopic = String(topic);
            responseTopic.replace("request", "response");
            client.publish(responseTopic.c_str(), get_gpio_status().c_str());
        } else if (strcmp(method, "setGpioStatus") == 0) {
            // Handle setGpioStatus method
            bool enabled = doc["params"]["enabled"];
            set_gpio_status(enabled);
            String responseTopic = String(topic);
            responseTopic.replace("request", "response");
            client.publish(responseTopic.c_str(), get_gpio_status().c_str());
            client.publish("v1/devices/me/attributes", get_gpio_status().c_str());
        } else {
            // Unknown method, log an error or handle accordingly
            Serial.println("Unknown method received");
        }
    }

    // Function to get the current GPIO status
    String get_gpio_status() {
        DynamicJsonDocument doc(200);
        doc[String(GPIO_PIN)] = gpioState;
        String strPayload;
        serializeJson(doc, strPayload);
        Serial.print("GPIO status: ");
        Serial.println(strPayload);
        return strPayload;
    }

    // Function to set the GPIO status
    void set_gpio_status(boolean enabled) {
        digitalWrite(GPIO_PIN, enabled ? HIGH : LOW);
        gpioState = enabled;
    }

    // Function to initialize WiFi connection
    void InitWiFi() {
        Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
        WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
            delay(500);
            Serial.print(".");
        }
        Serial.println("\nConnected to WiFi");
    }

    // Function to reconnect to the MQTT server
    void reconnect() {
        while (!client.connected()) {
            status = WiFi.status();
            if (status != WL_CONNECTED) {
                WiFi.begin(WIFI_AP, WIFI_PASSWORD);
                while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
                    delay(500);
                    Serial.print(".");
                }
                Serial.println("\nReconnected to WiFi");
            }
            Serial.print("Connecting to ThingsBoard...");
            if (client.connect("ESP8266 Device", TOKEN, NULL)) {
                Serial.println(" connected");
                client.subscribe("v1/devices/me/rpc/request/+");
                client.publish("v1/devices/me/attributes", get_gpio_status().c_str());
            } else {
                Serial.print(" failed, rc=");
                Serial.print(client.state());
                Serial.println("; retrying in 5 seconds");
                delay(5000);
            }
        }
    }


The part of the json object "param": "{"pin": "{5}", "enabled": true}' is not a valid json object, where it is come from and how it is enclosed. A valid json object should be something like "param": {"pin": 5, "enabled": true} or "param":{"pin": {5}, "enabled": true}.
